# Update multiple values in a single column based on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert the following:

```
Jan = 0.08745  
Feb = 0.07605  
Mar = 0.08745  
Apr = 0.08365  
May = 0.09125  
Jun = 0.07985  
Jul = 0.08365  
Aug = 0.08745  
Sep = 0.07224  
Oct = 0.08745  
Nov = 0.08365  
Dec = 0.07985
```

Into a table [Phasing] with the following columns:

```
[DateKey](YYYYMM, int/not null),  
[VersionKey](XXXX, int/not null),  
[TypeKey](SmallInt, Not Null),  
[Multiplier](0.000, decimal(20,10))
```

I want to:

```
UPDATE [Phasing] 

SET [Multiplier] = 0.08745

WHERE 
[TypeKey] = 1
[VersionKey] = 1234
[DateKey] = 201801

SET [Multiplier] = 0.07605  

WHERE 
[TypeKey] = 1
[VersionKey] = 1234
[DateKey] = 201802  

etc....
```

I need to do this for 3x versions (1234, 4321, 9876) out of about 15.

I'm currently getting a syntax error on the first where clause:

```
"Incorrect syntax near 'VersionKey'."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may only do a single `UPDATE` per statement.  So, your options are doing several separate updates, or you may do a single update using a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE [Phasing] 
SET [Multiplier] = CASE WHEN [DateKey] = 201801
                        THEN 0.08745
                        WHEN [DateKey] = 201802
                        THEN 0.07605 END
WHERE
    [TypeKey] = 1 AND [VersionKey] = 1234 AND
    [DateKey] IN (201801, 201802);
```